# Как заставить Garbage collector не уничтожать объект в памяти

Tags: java, java-ee, сборщик-мусора

После прочтения нескольких статей, стало понятно что `Garbage Collector`, самостоятельно определяет какие объекты стали 'мусором' и самостоятельно очищает память от этих объектов.

Вызов метода для сбора мусора не принесет никаких результатов, так как `garbage collector`, самостоятельно заботится о все операциях и чтобы ничего не сломалось игнорирует принудительные команды сбора мусора.

**Вопрос в следующем:** можно ли заставить сборщик мусора не удалять объект из памяти и в дальнейшем получить его?

Comment: да - Вам нужно сохранить хотя бы одну ссылку на этот объект.

Comment: А если без этого?

Comment: напишите свой GC.

Comment: можно собрать jvm без сборщика мусора, а почему нет?)

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa А как вы хотите получать объект на который нет ссылок?

Comment: видимо встроиться внутрь GC и пробежавшись найти свой объект:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хотите, чтобы объект не удалялся garbage collector'ом, есть несколько вариантов:

1. сохранить ссылку на этот объект
2. сделать ссылку phantom reference или переопределить метод finalize, и при помощи данных механизмов "воскрешать" объект.
3. сделать свою сборку jvm без сборки мусора, благо исходники есть
4. сериализовать объект и спрятать его в offheap